# ./node_modules/react-router/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' in node_modules\react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

TENGO ESTE MENSAJE EN REACT

> ./node_modules/react-router/index.js

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\appReact\restaurantcliente\node_modules\react-router'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Lo solucione con esta linea en la consola

```
npm install --save react-router@next history
```